# Why Unity does not take GetAxis?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a code:

```
    void Start()
    {
        playeRb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        xInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        zInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            playeRb.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed * zInput * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
```

Set xInput and Zinput how public for to see, is Unity take my params, but after pressing "W" both of them equally zero. Whats a problem?

Comment: You're only setting the input variables in `Start`, so therefore they are only set once and are never updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do these in `Update` ... a `float` is a **value** type => not passed as reference ... you are storing only one original value and then never update it anymore

Then you do **NOT** want to mix a `Rigidbody` (physics engine) with direct movements applied via `Transform`!

Rather use e.g. [`Rigidbody.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html)

```
void Update()
{
    xInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    zInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    playeRb.MovePosition(Vector3.forward * speed * zInput * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

or if your object should still be able to react to physics you rather will want to use [`Rigidbody.velocity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html) like

```
void Update()
{
    xInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    zInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    var movement = Vector3.forward * zInput + Vector3.right * xInput;
    movement = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(movement, 1f);

    playeRb.velocity = movement * speed * * Time.deltaTime;
}
```